# Neo4j - Counting Nodes with Labels

Tags: neo4j

I'd like a query that counts how many nodes have each label in the dataset.  For instance:

LabelA   100
 LabelB   200

I can do this for each individual label with something like

```
MATCH (n:LabelA) return count(n);
```

But, I'd like to do it for every label in one command.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try something like this

```
MATCH (n) 
RETURN count(labels(n)), labels(n);
```

This will return the sum of the labels in the first column and the label name in the second.

Comment: That works, a follow-up question, does the distinct modifier apply to just "count(labels(n))" or to the set of "count(labels(n)), labels(n)"?

Comment: I think it applies only to the set of labels, this is, the collection that returns  the function labels(n), because count(labels(n)) is an aggregate value. Anyways, maybe the modifier isn't necessary.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is redundant here (at least in neo 4.2).

Answer (score 9):

A quick alternative here, for single labels only, [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/database-introspection/meta/) offers a quick means of using the counts store to get the counts:

```
CALL apoc.meta.stats() YIELD labels
RETURN labels
```