# How to get different labels and their count in neo4j by cypher query?

Tags: count, neo4j, cypher

I was needing to check what different labels present in graph database neo4j.

How to get different labels and their count in neo4j by cypher query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's surprisingly complex to get a count per label since nodes can have multiple labels and `labels (n)` returns a collection of strings representing those labels. On a graph consisting of three nodes and two labels, as `{:A}`, `{:B}` and `{:A:B}`, `labels (n)` returns three distinct string collections. Instead of counting two nodes with `:A` and two nodes with `:B`, the result would be one for each of the three label combinations. See [console](http://console.neo4j.org/r/lxoasa). To aggregate per label, not per label collection, you'd have to group by the values within collection, which is cumbersome.

I have an ugly way to do it, maybe someone can suggest a better one: first find out max number of labels any node has.

```
MATCH (n)
RETURN max(length(labels(n)))
```

Then chain that many queries with `UNION`, counting nodes by the label at position `i` in the collection, where `i` starts at 0 and increments to the max-1. If the nodes have at most 3 labels,

```
MATCH (n)
RETURN labels (n)[0] as name, count (n) as cnt
UNION MATCH (n)
RETURN labels (n)[1] as name, count (n) as cnt
UNION MATCH (n)
RETURN labels (n)[2] as name, count (n) as cnt
```

This aggregates the label counts correctly, but it returns a `null` count for every case where the index is out of the collection bounds. For the first return (the `[0]` index) this signifies nodes that don't have a label. For the other lines, the null count similarly signifies nodes with less labels than queried for, but this information is irrelevant, so can be ignored

```
MATCH (n)
RETURN labels (n)[0] as name, count (n) as cnt
UNION MATCH (n)
WITH labels (n)[1] as name, count (n) as cnt
WHERE name IS NOT NULL
RETURN name, cnt
UNION MATCH (n)
WITH labels (n)[2] as name, count (n) as cnt
WHERE name IS NOT NULL
RETURN name, cnt
```

I'm sure this could be done more gracefully, but that's as far as I got.

Comment: Very nice and comprehensive answer, @jjaderberg!

Answer (score 30):

I finally found a solution to the multiple label problem that is less complicated:

```
MATCH (a) WITH DISTINCT LABELS(a) AS temp, COUNT(a) AS tempCnt
UNWIND temp AS label
RETURN label, SUM(tempCnt) AS cnt
```

Comment: Unbelievable. FAST too. Very underrated answer. :)

Answer (score 7):

With this cypher query we can get different labels present in neo4j and their count.

```
MATCH (n) RETURN DISTINCT LABELS(n), COUNT(n)
```

Comment: That works if you don't have multiple overlapping label combinations. Try it on the sample data in [Neo4j console](http://console.neo4j.org/r/lxoasa), it returns `[Matrix]`, `[Crew]` and `[Matrix, Crew]` as three separate results.

Comment: ohh. I didn't considered multiple label's on same node. Thanks for answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage [apoc library](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/database-introspection/meta/) meta graph as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52489029 --> run the code below, it works even if there is more labels attached to a one node.

```
CALL apoc.meta.stats() YIELD labels
RETURN labels
```